# Maven test execution error

Tags: java, maven

When I use Maven to run unit tests for my Java EE application, I get a strange error: **org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to copy an artifact to the working directory**
caused by a **java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Work\Projets\RT_GAF\Dev\Sandbox\client\target\classes (Access is denied)**

The Maven structure of the application is :

- ...\Dev\Sandbox\ : root of the application, this is a 'pom' module that lists the other modules

  ...\Dev\Sandbox\common\ : 'jar' module, contains classes common to the client and server, and tests (JUnit only)

  ...\Dev\Sandbox\client\ : 'jar' module, contains smart client side classes (Swing stuff, etc) and tests (JUnit only), deployed through Java Web Start

  ...\Dev\Sandbox\server\ : 'jar' module, contains server-side classes (MVC stuff, DAO, etc) and tests (both JUnit and Arquillian)

  ...\Dev\Sandbox\webapp\ : 'war' module, contains web items (JSP, images, web.xml, etc), ABSOLUTELY NO CLASSES OR TESTS, will receive the 'common' and 'server' jars

  ...\Dev\Sandbox\application\ : 'ear' module, contains application.xml, will receive the 'webapp' war

As explained, we have JUnit and Arquillian tests.

Test execution "mvn test -Pjbossas-remote-6" (the profile is used for Arquillian tests to tunnel in-container tests execution to JBoss 6) from the root of the application **fails**:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Sandbox ........................................... SUCCESS [0.003s]
[INFO] Sandbox Common .................................... SUCCESS [45.003s]
[INFO] Sandbox Client .................................... SUCCESS [20.226s]
[INFO] Sandbox Server .................................... SUCCESS [49.064s]
[INFO] Sandbox WebApp .................................... FAILURE [3.128s]
[INFO] Sandbox Application ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:57.663s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 21 10:07:03 CEST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 107M/478M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo.webstart:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:jnlp-download-servlet (default) on project sandbox-webapp: Unable to copy an artifact to the working directory: D:\Work\Projets\RT_GAF\Dev\Sandbox\client\target\classes (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo.webstart:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:jnlp-download-servlet (default) on project sandbox-webapp: Unable to copy an artifact to the working directory
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to copy an artifact to the working directory
    at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.JnlpDownloadServletMojo.retrieveJarResources(JnlpDownloadServletMojo.java:454)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.JnlpDownloadServletMojo.execute(JnlpDownloadServletMojo.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Work\Projets\RT_GAF\Dev\Sandbox\client\target\classes (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:950)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.AbstractBaseJnlpMojo.copyJarAsUnprocessedToDirectoryIfNecessary(AbstractBaseJnlpMojo.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.JnlpDownloadServletMojo.retrieveJarResources(JnlpDownloadServletMojo.java:423)
    ... 22 more
```

As you can see, tests in 'common', 'client' and 'server' modules are executed correctly (yay !), but the tests execution stops at the 'webapp' module level even though this module contains absolutely no classes (no business classes, no tests).

Note that we can see Java Web Start references in the stack trace ("**JnlpDownloadServletMojo**").

More surprising, the error mentions **a path of the 'client' module** while the error happens during the processing of the 'webapp' module.

If i try to execute the tests **directly** in the 'webapp' module, it **works fine** (blank lines removed) :

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Do you guys known what is going on? Why does the tests execution stop? And how I can fix this?

Thank you for your time.

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You're running Maven 3, right? Did you upgrade from Maven 2 recently? One of your plugins was written for Maven 2 and hasn't been updated for 3. Maven 3 added support for resolving dependencies to modules in the reactor for the current build, which is a really great feature, but it means that a module dependency can be resolved to a directory now instead of only jar files. Plugins that assume that dependencies are *always* jar files fail like this.

To illustrate, imagine you have modules `foo` and `bar`, which are both modules of `top-level`, and `bar` depends on `foo`. With Maven 2, if you run `mvn compile` in `top-level`, it will, of course compile both `foo` and `bar`. What it *won't* do is compile `bar` against the just-compiled version of `foo`. In other words, if you just added a new method to a class in `foo` and a class in `bar` uses it, you'd get a compilation error by running `mvn compile`. That's because Maven 2 only has the ability to resolve artifacts from a repository, and since you didn't install the new version of `foo` to the local repository, the method isn't available to `bar`.

That was pretty annoying and a heavily-requested change, so Maven 3 changes it. With `mvn compile` under Maven 3, the `${project.build.outputDirectory}` of `foo` will be what the dependency in `bar` resolves to. With this approach, that `mvn compile` will work because first `foo` is compiled, and then when `bar` is compiled, instead of the latest `foo` jar in the local repo being used, it uses `foo/target/classes` to satisfy the dependency, which, of course, has the latest version of `foo` in it.

What you're seeing is an old plugin that assumes--as was true in Maven 2--that depedencies always resolve to files. Under Maven 3, that's not always true.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I found several outdated plugins :
  maven-ear-plugin ......................................... 2.5 -> 2.6
  maven-jar-plugin ..................................... 2.3.1 -> 2.3.2
  maven-javadoc-plugin ..................................... 2.7 -> 2.8
  maven-resources-plugin ............................... 2.4.2 -> 2.4.3
I upgraded them, but this does not change anything.

Comment: From the stack trace, I think that the faulty plugin is the WebStart plugin. I'm using webstart-maven-plugin 1.0-beta-1. Is this a known issue? Are there known solutions? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Manually updated webstart-maven-plugin to 1.0-beta-2. Same error message.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error, it seems pretty clear that the user running mvn doesn't have access rights to D:\Work\Projets\RT_GAF\Dev\Sandbox\client\target\classes Check the directories read and write access settings.

Other then that I can't say without seeing the pom files.

Comment: I noticed that too. I can say that I have complete access to all the files and folders involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your dir have this file? Please check it carefully.

Once I used **ant**, I have this problem too. Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Run eclipse as administrator.
Steps:
Right click on the eclipse and say run as administrator.